# Speed up a Monte Carlo in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, random, montecarlo

I am running a Monte Carlo in Excel. To represent the distribution of demand for each product SKU during each month, I am using the following formula over 500 times:

`=IFERROR(BETA.INV(RAND(),(1+4*(D35-D31)/(D27-D31)),(1+4*(D27-D35)/(D27-D31)),D31,D27),0)`

So, that's over 500 `RAND()` volatile functions at a time.

The output from each iteration of a formula is stored in a table. I have a VBA to handle that:

```
Sub QARLO_Products()
'runs on QARLO_P!, for forecasting product
    Range("Q7:OC100000").ClearContents
    For Iteration = 1 To Range("G1").Value
        Range("I1").Value = Range("G1").Value - Iteration
        'For QMIN Zinc-Bulk
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 17) = Iteration
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 18) = Cells(39, 4)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 19) = Cells(39, 5)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 20) = Cells(39, 6)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 21) = Cells(39, 7)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 22) = Cells(39, 8)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 23) = Cells(39, 9)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 24) = Cells(39, 10)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 25) = Cells(39, 11)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 26) = Cells(39, 12)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 27) = Cells(39, 13)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 28) = Cells(39, 14)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 29) = Cells(39, 15)
        'For QMIN Zinc-Jugs
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 30) = Iteration
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 31) = Cells(40, 4)
.... blah, blah, blah and so on for all products....
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 444) = Cells(561, 14)
        Cells(6 + Iteration, 445) = Cells(561, 15)
   Next Iteration
End Sub
```

The left-hand side of these statements represent the table location for recording output data, the right-hand side are the outputs from the above mentioned formula.

I notice that this VBA runs through each and every line in series. Each line causes all 500 volatile `RAND()` functions to recalculate. One iteration of this VBA takes 30 seconds on all 8 cores of a Core i7/ 32GB RAM. I want to run 5,000 iterations on a regular basis.

Can you suggest methods to make this model run more efficiently?

- Make one cell a `RAND()` and then have all 500 reference it?
- Restructure the VBA?

I have done all the basic/general things to make Excel run more efficiently.

Comment: @pizzettix I meant basics like [this](https://www.exceltip.com/tips/how-to-speed-up-excel.html) . Your screenupdating script is advanced (to me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One small change might make a large difference.

Read and write a large range with a single call into / from an array.
I can't check the exact code now, but you can say something like

```
   Range(Cells(6 + Iteration, 18), Cells(6+Iteration, 455).Value = Range(Cells(39,4), Cells(561,15).Value
```

Or by splitting the read and write so you can check things in the Debugger

```
   Dim TempValues As Variant ' Really a 2D array of variants

   TempValues = Range(Cells(39,4), Cells(561,15)).Value
   Range(Cells(6 + Iteration, 18), Cells(6 + Iteration, 455)).Value = TempValues
```

By doing this you will read / write everything in one shot, and by writing only once you will once force the volatile calculation to happen once, instead of on every write.

This looks like a nice write-up about reading and writing ranges as arrays, and checking things out under the debugger: https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-working-with-arrays.htm

Some other ideas:

- Replace the volatile function with your own rand function in VBA (which maybe just calls `Rnd` internally). Then if will only get now values (and recalculate) when you explictly recalculate all.
- Switch the sheet to  manual calculation during your 'recording' loop to prevent the volatile cells from calculating while you're writing to the sheet.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean with "I have done all the basic/general things to make Excel run more efficiently"? Did you try to turn of screenupdating, and so on?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Place your macro code here

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make Excel more efficient you have to consider to run your Monte Carlo simulation entirely in VBA. Store the results in an array and plot these in the excel sheet at the end of all the simulations.

Answer (score 0):

In addition what others said you could rewrite your Application.Worksheetfunction.Norminv(..) as in https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/147479-checking-for-undefined-result-from-some-math-functions/ and replace the rnd() part in it by a Halton-Sequence. It also offers the option to repeat your results and speeds up the whole process considerably..